# Удалить ненужные фотографии

Tags: windows, изображения, любой-язык

Суть вопроса: есть 5000 фотографий, есть список в excel, точных названий нужных фотографий (их 1000)

Как можно удалить все кроме этих 1000 фотографий? Не перерывая в ручную

Comment: Да просто список из Экселя экспортировать, записать в файл, а дальше - что там нужно? скопировать? - набросать... Вплоть до `bat`-файла :)

Comment: Если знаете Visual Basic, можно в экселе наверное накидать скриптец.

Comment: С Visual Basic знаком, но сейчас нужно бы решение попроще. С .bat файлом подошло бы. Но что в него вписать? :)

Comment: Все это работает но эта команда удаляет все из списка, а по запросу спрашивали как удалить все кроме тех что в списке. Есть такой вариант?
Ситуация такая же. На сайте куча фоток, я могу получиться список используемых, нужно удалить все остальные.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Простейший путь - выделяем в Экселе нужный список файлов, Ctrl-C :), вставляем в обычном текстовом редакторе в файл, скажем, `list.txt` - чтоб по одному в строке.

Дальше - одна команда

```
for /F %f in (list.txt) do del /Q %f
```

Примерно так... И никакого программирования не нужно :)

Если имена файлов с пробелами - можно, например, воспользоваться ключом `delims` и кавычками - словом, смотрите, что напишет `for /?`...

Но рекомендовал бы сначала убедиться, что все верно -

```
for /F %f in (list.txt) do echo del /Q %f
```

а то мало ли... Удаление - оно такое, не самое безопасное :)

P.S. Простите за лирическое отступление - но, похоже, зря теперь не учат работать в командной строке, как когда-то во времена DOS с этого начинали... И даже Far или там FileCommander далеко не на каждой машине найдешь. А ведь просто в командной строке можно много что сделать...

Comment: "for /F %f in (list.txt) do del /Q %f" необходимо проделывать в командной строке?

Comment: Ну да. Если писать в `bat`-файл - то надо не забыть % удвоить...

Comment: А если файлы с пробелами?  (Нижними подчеркиваниями) Как тогда команда будет выглядеть?

Comment: Так, что там точно в именах файлов не будет? `*`? Ну, пишем `for /F "DELIMS=*" %f in (list.txt) do echo del /Q "%f"` - должно сработать... ну, а как убедимся, что все OK - понятно, `echo` удаляем...

Comment: У меня просто некоторые фото подписаны примерно так 343_name_3434.jpg Не будет проблем если я этим кодом воспользуюсь for /F %f in (list.txt) do del /Q %f ?

Comment: Раз пробелов нет - можно никакие кавычки не писать. Хватит того, что вы написали. Еще раз рекомендую для осторожности сначала запустить с `echo`. Ну и, если имена у вас без полного пути - то не забудьте запуститься в том каталоге, где эти файлы лежат.

Comment: `И никакого программирования не нужно` — так что же это тогда, если не программирование ;)

Comment: @Андрей Азы пользования :)